# Можно ли блок со свойством position: sticky; растянуть до нижнего края окна?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Суть проблемы такая: нужно растянуть блок `sticky-block` со свойством `position: sticky;` до нижнего края области просмотра окна браузера, так что бы его нижняя граница при смещении верхней границы оставалась фиксированной по нижнему краю отображаемого окна (блок все время должен быть виден целиком и увеличиться на смещаемую разницу). Не могу сообразить как это сделать. Что то мне подсказывает, что это невозможно. Может быть есть возможность реализовать данную задумку без `position: sticky;`?

В примере блоку задана высота 50% рандомно.

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {font-size: 36px; margin: 0;}

.top-block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 0.05em solid white;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.underheader {
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.main-section {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.headpost {
    position: relative;
    height: 7em;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.post {
    position: relative;
    height: 30em;
    background-color: green;
}

.bw {
  background-color: red;
}

.aside-menu {
  background-color: silver;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 0.2em solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="head">
    <div class="top-block"></div>
    <div class="underheader"></div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="headpost">
        <h1>шапка</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <aside class="sidebar">
        <nav class="aside-menu">
          <div class="sticky-block">
            <h1>sticky</h1>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </aside>
      <section class="main-section">
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-1-diseases">
          <h1>первый</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post article" id="anchor-scrl-2-diseases">
          <h1>второй</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-3-diseases">
          <h1>третий</h1>
        </article>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Мои мысли на эту тему: без js в данном случае не обойтись. Нужно блок позиционировать при помощи `position: fixed;` Отнять в функции js от блока высоту шапки и закрепить его по нижнему краю. При скроле нижнего края шапки до верхнего края окна, вернуть блоку 100% высоту. Но я не силен в js и пока сам написать эту функцию не могу...

Comment: Я ничего не понял, что именно Вы хотите сделать с `sticky-block`?, почему вдруг он sticky?, никакого CSS для него не присутствует. Советую переписать вопрос, и/или сделать схематический набросок того что Вы по итогу хотели бы получить. Если Вы заранее знаете размеры блока то никакой JS вам не понадобиться, скорее всего можно будет обойтись функцией calc()

Comment: Перефразирую. При загрузке страницы `.sticky-block` должен отображаться целиком: верхний край блока под блоком `.headpost`, нижний край блока на уровне нижнего края области просмотра окна браузера. При скроле страницы блок `headpost` не фиксирован и смещается вверх. Нужно чтобы верхний край `sticky-block` так же смещался, блок увеличивался, а нижний край остался фиксированным. До скрола размер `sticky-block` `100vh - 'высота .top-block' - 'высота .headpost'`, при скроле страницы вниз размер `sticky-block` `100vh - 'высота .top-block'`, у `sticky-block` `position: fixed;`

Comment: Однако, при скроле до футера блок с `position: fixed;` перекроет футер, а это не нужно. Поэтому я изначально и решил попробовать реализовать эту задачу с применением свойства `position: sticky;` данному блоку

Comment: @СтаниславСтрижаков --- Проблема в том, что если управлять залипанием элемента по событию scroll через JS, то вы неизбежно получите scroll-linked effects, и глюки в браузерах в которых реализован асинхронный скролл вместо синхронного. Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

Comment: @NoSkill --- иными словами, поставленную задачу решить невозможно? Существует ли какой-либо способ добиться описанной задачи?

Comment: Безглючного решения с onScroll по всей видимости не существует... По факту событие onScroll в JS может прилететь уже после того, как страничка визуально прокрутилась куда-то вверх или вниз. То есть ваш фикс элемента по высоте в обработчике события onScroll будет запаздывать от визуального скроллирования и вы получите глюки.

Comment: Я лично попробовал бы запустить бесконечный цикл `requestAnimationFrame`... в нем определял бы текущую позицию скролла, и в зависимости от неё перерисовывал бы высоту элемента. Хотя, честно говоря, не знаю получится ли так... И к тому же при загрузке страницы, пока не начнет работать JS элемент будет иметь неправильную высоту, но если у сайта есть глобальный лоадер, то этот эффект будет скрыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот просто идея с `requestAnimationFrame`. Эта функция тоже асинхронная, но позволяет избежать потери кадров и повысить эффективность перерисовки. Перерисовка все равно будет запаздывать от визуального скролирования, но не так явно, как с событием onScroll.

```js
var head = window.document.getElementById('head'),
    foot = window.document.getElementById('foot'),
    side = window.document.getElementById('side');

window.requestAnimationFrame(function step() {
  var offset = Math.max(0, head.offsetHeight - window.pageYOffset) + 
               Math.max(0, foot.offsetHeight + window.pageYOffset +
                 window.document.documentElement.clientHeight -
                 window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
  side.style.minHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight - offset + 'px';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#head {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#foot {
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#side {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

#main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: 3000px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">head</div>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="side">side</div>
  <div id="main">main</div>
</div>
<div id="foot">foot</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Comment: У данного варианта есть 1 недостаток: при добавлении снизу футера и скроле страницы в самый низ блок `side` смещается на размер футера вверх за пределы viewport

Comment: В вычислениях нужно тогда учитывать и футер, помимо хедера.

Comment: Обновил код, добавил футер, и еще один елемент `wrap`, для того, чтобы `side` катался только в пределах своей области (так как у него `position: sticky`). И кстати, `side` и `main` можно сделать flex-элементами... у меня в данном случае сделано с применением `float: left`.

Comment: еще раз спасибо. сам пока не могу прописывать код на js (только начал изучать).  под свой шаблон код адаптировал, с flex-элементами все работает. для фиксированного блока в шапке вводил еще 1 переменную `headblock` и задавал вместо 0 высоту переменной `var offset = Math.max(headblock.offsetHeight, headblock.offsetHeight + head.offsetHeight - window.pageYOffset)` . Сейчас добавил строку из нового кода и теперь всё рабоает как часы. Без помощи на разобрался бы.

Comment: Обратите внимание, также я избавился в вычислениях от `vh`. Так как единицы `vh` - это единицы viewport, и они не учитывают размеры scrollbar-ов. Если вдруг внезапно появится горизонтальный скролбар, то вместо `100vh` (вытоты viewport) лучше использовать `documentElement.clientHeight` (клиентскую высоту документа).

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант нужен?

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {font-size: 36px; margin: 0;}

.top-block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 0.05em solid white;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.underheader {
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.main-section {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.headpost {
    position: relative;
    height: 7em;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.post {
    position: relative;
    height: 30em;
    background-color: green;
}

.bw {
  background-color: red;
}

.aside-menu {
  background-color: silver;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 0.2em solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: calc(100vh - (48px + 20px));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="head">
    <div class="top-block"></div>
    <div class="underheader"></div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="headpost">
        <h1>шапка</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <aside class="sidebar">
        <nav class="aside-menu">
          <div class="sticky-block">
            <h1>sticky</h1>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </aside>
      <section class="main-section">
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-1-diseases">
          <h1>первый</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post article" id="anchor-scrl-2-diseases">
          <h1>второй</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-3-diseases">
          <h1>третий</h1>
        </article>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: По моему автор хочет чтобы sticky как минимум всегда занимал всю свою площадь по высоте, и до залипания и после... И только если его контент не помещается, уходил под вьюпорт.

Comment: При таком желание нужно заменить `max-height` на `min-height`

Comment: При `min-height` до скролирования элемент заезжает под вьюпорт.

Comment: спасибо за предоставленный вариант. я не знал, что так можно задать высоту блоку в css. значительно облегчает задачу. Хотя про эту функцию в одном из предыдущих комментариев писали...

Answer (score 0):

как то так. попытался написать код на jquery, но он не рабочий...

```js
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(() => {

    let sticky = $('.sticky-block'),
      headfixed = $('.top-block'),
      headpost = $('.headpost'),
      activeSticky = $('.active-sticky-block');
        
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
         sticky.height($(window).height() - headfixed.outerHeight() - headpost.outerHeight(););
         activeSticky.height($(window).height() - headfixed.outerHeight(););
        
         const position = $(this).scrollTop();
            
         sticky(function () {
                const top = $(this).offset().top + headfixed.outerHeight() + headpost.outerHeight();
                if (position <= top) {
                    sticky.removeClass('active-sticky-block');
                }
                else if (position > top) {
                    sticky.addClass('active-sticky-block');
                }
            });
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {font-size: 36px; margin: 0;}

.top-block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 0.05em solid white;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.underheader {
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.main-section {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.headpost {
    position: relative;
    height: 7em;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.post {
    position: relative;
    height: 30em;
    background-color: green;
}

.bw {
  background-color: red;
}

.sticky-block {
  background-color: silver;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 0.2em solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header class="head">
    <div class="top-block"></div>
    <div class="underheader"></div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="headpost">
        <h1>шапка</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <aside class="sidebar">
          <div class="sticky-block">
            <h1>sticky</h1>
          </div>
      </aside>
      <section class="main-section">
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-1-diseases">
          <h1>первый</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post article" id="anchor-scrl-2-diseases">
          <h1>второй</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-3-diseases">
          <h1>третий</h1>
        </article>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Знаю, что код написан с ошибками. Помогите исправить, кто знает как.

Answer (score 0):

Всем огромное спасибо за проявленный интерес и помощь в решении данной задачи. С помощью Ваших подсказок сейчас могу написать то, чего хочу добиться. Данный вариант корявый, блок плавно смещается не синхронно скролу, а по времени. По-другому самостоятельно написать код пока не могу. Помогите в написании кода для синхронного со скролом смещением блока. Страница с прелоадером и отображается только после загрузки скриптов, так что багов с преждевременным скролом быть не должно

```js
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 108) {
                $('.sticky-block').addClass('fixed');
            } 
            else {
                $('.sticky-block').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
```

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {font-size: 36px; margin: 0;}

.top-block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 0.05em solid white;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.underheader {
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.main-section {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.headpost {
    position: relative;
    height: 7em;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.post {
    position: relative;
    height: 30em;
    background-color: green;
}

.bw {
  background-color: red;
}

.sticky-block {
  background-color: silver;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 0.2em solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 11em);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.sticky-block.fixed {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 4em);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header class="head">
    <div class="top-block"></div>
    <div class="underheader"></div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header>
      <div class="headpost">
        <h1>шапка</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="wrapper">
      <aside class="sidebar">
          <div class="sticky-block">
            <h1>sticky</h1>
          </div>
      </aside>
      <section class="main-section">
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-1-diseases">
          <h1>первый</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post article" id="anchor-scrl-2-diseases">
          <h1>второй</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-3-diseases">
          <h1>третий</h1>
        </article>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```